# PrimeNG sending data FROM Dynamic Dialog to its parent component

Tags: modal-dialog, primeng

I have a fully functional PrimeNG Dialog working. I'm passing data to it with the `DynamicDialogService.open` but how do we send data back to the parent?

Sending data back doesnt appear in the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dynamicdialog) that I can see.

```
this.dialogService.open(SomeModalComponent, {
  ...
  data: {
    someData: 'some string'
  },
}
```

In the dialog we use the data

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.config?.data?.someData); // 'some string'
}
```

Comment: What about a service using rxjs and a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: Yes, I think this dialog -> parent communication is not built into this dialog. So the answer seems to be that "we can't".

Comment: Why don't you try to send data back after dialog close using DynamicDialogRef.close() and subscribe to dialog reference in parent component to get the data that sent from dialog to parent.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add ref in your parent component `ref: DynamicDialogRef;`.
2. Add `DialogService` in your component providers.
3. Open dialog :

```
  this.ref = this.dialogService.open(UploadFilesDialogComponent, {
      header: this.translate.instant('INVOICES.attachFiles'),
      width: '30vw',
      contentStyle: { "max-height": "500px", "overflow": "auto" },
      data: this.invoiceFiles,
      closable: false

    });
```

4. Inject `DynamicDialogRef` in dialog component `public ref: DynamicDialogRef`
5. In dialog component send data back using `close()` function :
   `this.ref.close(this.uploadedFiles)`
6. In parent component

```
this.ref.onClose.subscribe((files: customUploadFile[]) => {
     // put your code here
    });
```

Comment: Great related answer, not the answer to the question but part of it. Within the dialog a user may take any action and We need real time data to react to it appropriately. Also I’m seeing that because of the inherent architecture of a modal dialog we should keep request data out of its logic if possible. So there is great need to have a very streamlined access to what the user is doing there while they do it. Currently I’ve setup a service pattern for each modal and it works by updating behaviorsubjects as I/O